# Jupyter notebook does not launch

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I installed Anaconda today, but have been facing issues to launch Jupyter notebook. I tried out solutions online, such as starting it from the command prompt, but nothing has worked.

When I try to open, it gives me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Avi\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6,
> in 
> from notebook.notebookapp import main
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Avi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py",
> line 51, in 
> from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Avi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq_*init*_.py",
> line 47, in 
> from zmq import backend
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Avi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init*_.py",
> line 40, in 
> reraise(*exc_info)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Avi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py",
> line 34, in reraise
> raise value
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Avi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init*_.py",
> line 27, in 
> _ns = select_backend(first)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Avi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py",
> line 28, in select_backend
> mod = **import**(name, fromlist=public_api)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Avi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_*init*_.py",
> line 6, in
>
> ```
> from . import (constants, error, message, context, ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module
> ```
>
> 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import)
> (C:\Users\Avi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_*init*_.py)

Comment: Try uninstalling other python installations, such as the one at `C:\Users\Avi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38`. It is causing conflicts

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a conda environment 'test' with a specific python environment, activate the environment and then run jupyter notebook. On anaconda prompt run the below commands.

```
conda create -n test "python>=3.5,<3.8" ipython 
conda activate test
jupyter notebook
```